# Can you save the data from the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools Windows to review after application is done processing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, can you save the data that is accumulated in all the windows (Timeline, CPU Usage, Memory Usage, etc) of the Diagnostic Tools to review after the application completes?

Comment: I've added a Visual Studio feature request for this feature.  Please upvote it at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1283355/memory-diagnostics-tool-snapshot-add-ability-to-ex.html

Answer (score 13):

Currently it is not possible to save data for Diagnostics Tools while debugging. However, it is possible to save data when running tool(s) from Diagnostics Hub (Debug > Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging).

Comment: Is this `Debug > Profiler > Start Profiler` in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Disappointed again with Visual Studio. The Performance Profiler doesn't even load in my case.

Comment: Man there is still no save button in VS 2019... And this thread is more than 4 years old......

Comment: i suppose they will find covid19 vaccine before the support of save button.

Comment: @BarışAkkurt  Looks like you were right ;)

Comment: I've added a Visual Studio feature request for this feature.  Please upvote it at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1283355/memory-diagnostics-tool-snapshot-add-ability-to-ex.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but if you go to Debug > IntelliTrace > Open IntelliTrace Settings > Advanced  and check "Store IntelliTrace recordings in this directory:", then you can at least get the IntelliTrace info back.  I don't see CPU or Memory usage though.

EDIT: Just realized you can do this for individutal sessions by choosing Debug > IntelliTrace > Save IntelliTrace Session when the application is in break mode.